# How to Program an Arduino Menu with 3 button?

Tags: c++, button, arduino, embedded

I want to Design an `Arduino` Program for `Arduino Uno`.

The Inputs Will be-

1. A Soil Moisture Sensor (Analog In).
2. A Soil Temperature Sensor DSXX series.
3. A DHT22 Sensor.
4. 3 Buttons (Up, Set, Down).
5. A RTC (any).

   Output Will be-

*A Relay for Water Pump and a Relay for Fogger.

*A 16x2 Display, using liquid crystal library, (non-I2C).

Basically, this will be an opensource project which I am doing.

The requirements are -

1.The Pump has to be switched ON based on 2 conditions-.

2.1st- The Soil Moisture must be less than the threshold value.

3.2nd- The Time should be Morning (6 AM to 9 AM) or Evening (4 PM to 6 PM).

Display the rest of the sensor values on a 16x2 Alphanumeric Display. 
Display the time on the same display after sensor values displayed.

Keep this doing in a loop until the menu is accessed. After exiting from the menu, the above loop to continue with modifications updates in the menu.

The user should be able to do the following using Menu-
 1. Set Button to Enter/Exit the Menu, Up button for scrolling the menu up, Dn button for scrolling the menu down. 
 2. Menu Items - 
               1. Set Clock Time -> Set Hr > Set Minute
               2. Turn On The Pump On/Off Manually.
               3. Change the Threshold value of the Soil Moisture at which pump should start.

I did the hardware with LCD and able to display the sensor values, can turn on and off the relays based on the readings from the soil. But I am unable to design the menu as I have never done that. 
Most of the time I trying to design a menu based on the codes on the internet, I am stuck in the menu at some point and could not get back to the loop again.
 Sometimes, I am unable to enter into sub-menus.

This is completely for personal hobby purpose, and once finished, I will upload it on the instructable. The scheduling of irrigation in agriculture is important to me, hence I am trying with `RTC`.

```
enter code here
/* Automatic Irrigation controller with Scheduling and Menu
* 16x2 LCD
* Button Control
* Multi Sensor
* Multi Crop
* Arduino Mega 2560
*/
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> //Display
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <DHT.h> // DHT 22

/* INPUT PINS */
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 12  // soil temperature sensor pin
#define SOIL_MOIST A7  // Soil Moisture Pin
#define UP_BUTTON (A0)
#define DN_BUTTON (A2)
#define SET_BUTTON (A1)
#define DHTPIN 13

/* RTC MODULE DS1302 */
#define DS1302_SCLK_PIN 2
#define DS1302_IO_PIN 14
#define DS1302_CE_PIN 15
#define bcd2bin(h,l)    (((h)*10) + (l))
#define bin2bcd_h(x)   ((x)/10)
#define bin2bcd_l(x)    ((x)%10)
#define DS1302_SECONDS           0x80
#define DS1302_MINUTES           0x82
#define DS1302_HOURS             0x84
#define DS1302_DATE              0x86
#define DS1302_MONTH             0x88
#define DS1302_DAY               0x8A
#define DS1302_YEAR              0x8C
#define DS1302_ENABLE            0x8E
#define DS1302_TRICKLE           0x90
#define DS1302_CLOCK_BURST       0xBE
#define DS1302_CLOCK_BURST_WRITE 0xBE
#define DS1302_CLOCK_BURST_READ  0xBF
#define DS1302_RAMSTART          0xC0
#define DS1302_RAMEND            0xFC
#define DS1302_RAM_BURST         0xFE
#define DS1302_RAM_BURST_WRITE   0xFE
#define DS1302_RAM_BURST_READ    0xFF
/* DHT 22 */
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)

/* OUTPUT PINS */
#define  PUMP_RELAY 16 
LiquidCrystal lcd(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11); // LCD Pins

/* INITIALIZE */
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz 
Arduino

/* VARIABLES */
int val=1000;
float hum; // HUMIDITY FROM DHT22
float temp; // TEMPERATURE FROM DHT22
int st,sm; // ST- SOIL TEMPERATURE FROM DS18B20, SM - SOIL MOISTURE FROM     
VEGETRONIX
int pump_stat =0; // THE WATER PUMP STATUS 0 FOR OFF, 1 FOR ON
int menu_state = 0; // 1, MENU IS BEING DISPLAYED, 0 WHEN NORMAL LOOP IS     
RUNNING

void setup() {
 pinMode(UP_BUTTON,INPUT); // 0 = Not pressed, 1 = pressed, pulled down
 pinMode(DN_BUTTON,INPUT);
 pinMode(SET_BUTTON,INPUT);
 dht.begin();
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.setCursor(1,0);
 lcd.print("Agri Sensor");
 lcd.setCursor(0,2); 
 lcd.print("Smart Agro");
 delay(2000);
 lcd.clear();
}


void loop() {
while (true) {
  ReadSensors();
  ReadButtons();
  SetOutputs();
  DisplayScreen();
}

}
void ReadSensors()
{
hum = dht.readHumidity();
temp= dht.readTemperature();
st= digitalRead(ONE_WIRE_BUS); // Will map it later
sm= analogRead(SOIL_MOIST); // Will map it later
}

void ReadButtons(){
  if (digitalRead(SET_BUTTON)){
    menu_state=1;
    menu_call();
    delay(1000);
  }

}
void SetOutputs(){
  if( sm<250 && pump_stat==0){   // Here the current time will be     
comparision will be added later from ds1302 rtc data
    digitalWrite(PUMP_RELAY, HIGH);   
    pump_stat = 1;
  }
  if( sm>900 && pump_stat==1){ // The current time should be within pre-    
programmed time to switch on the pump
    digitalWrite(PUMP_RELAY, LOW);
  }
}
void DisplayScreen(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Soil Temp");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print(st); 
  lcd.print(" Celcius "); 
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Soil Moisture");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print(sm); // mapping will be done later for sensor value to percentage
  lcd.print(" Percent"); 
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Humidity");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print(hum);
  lcd.print(" Percent"); 
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Air Temp");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print(temp); // mapping will be done later for sensor value to percentage
  lcd.print(" Celsius"); 
  delay(1000);

  /*
   * Display routine for rtc will be added soon
   */
}

// Main menu function
// Now all my confusion is here, how to operate this meny using buttons
int scroll; // for using in swtich case
void menu_call(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(" Main Menu");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print(" Press Up/Dn");
  while(menu_state==1)
  {
    switch(scroll){
    case 1:
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Threshold change");
    execute_threshold();
    menu_state=0;
    break;

    case 2:
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Pump Schedule");
    execute_schedule();
    menu_state=0;
    break;      
    }
  }

}
// sub menu functions
void execute_threshold(){
  return;
}
void execute_schedule(){
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat fluffy question, but I will try to give you some ideas on how to proceed.

As I understand it, your problem is that you want execution to continue in the background while the user is fiddling with the menu. But this is a problem since an Arduino only has a single execution thread.

First I would make a main loop in this style:

```
while (true) {
  ReadSensors()
  ReadButtons();
  SetOutputs();
  DisplayScreen();
}
```

Then I would make very sure to program all of those functions as so that they can be called multiple times in a row without problem causing issues, AND while making sure that none of them block or wait on anything. You want that loop to be running continuously.

If it is a problem if the sensors are read too quickly, then do something like:

```
void ReadSensors()
{
  if (now - lastRead < deltaTime)
    return;

  if (!SensorsReadyToBeRead()) {
    PrepareSensorsForRead(); // <- again make sure this does not contain any delays
    return;
  }

  ReadSensorDataIntoMemorySomehow(); // <- make sure this also does not contain any delays
}
```

You can do something similar for the outputs.

Then make a state machine for the menu:

```
Enum MenuStates {
  NO_MENU,
  MAIN_MENU,
  TIME_MENU,
  PUMP_MENU,
  ...
}
```

Possibly with a sub-state machine for each menu.

Then whenever you detect a button press you update the state of the state machine(s), and in the `DisplayScreen()` function you display something based on the current state of the state machine(s). Do make sure to only update the states in `ReadButtons()` though; state machines are relatively simple if you separate update and response, but quickly go off the rails in complexity if you have multiple places that change the state.

Anyway, a fluffy answer to a fluffy question - I hope you can use some of the ideas, but no guarantees that this is the *best* way of doing something like this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I have started coding as per your guidance. I am not a coder, starting fresh hence this fluffy kind of questions you may face. Sorry for that. Please see the latest edit for my code. And suggest some improvements. 
Regards.